# How to set ImplicitWait in Selenium 3.1.0

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

After upgrading `Selenium WebDriver 3.1.0` I received warning on

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

> Warning   11  'OpenQA.Selenium.ITimeouts.SetScriptTimeout(System.TimeSpan)' is obsolete: 'This method will be removed in a future version. Please set the AsynchronousJavaScript property instead.'

So I changed it to

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

It worked fine with `ChromeDriver`, but when I tried `FireFoxDriver` the test failed on this line, throwing an exception

> Result Message:    System.InvalidOperationException : Missing 'type'
>   parameter (IndexOutOfBounds) Result StackTrace:    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.InternalExecute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary'2 parameters) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteTimeouts.ExecuteSetTimeout(String
>   timeoutType, TimeSpan timeToWait) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteTimeouts.set_ImplicitWait(TimeSpan value)
>   at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events.EventFiringWebDriver.EventFiringTimeouts.set_ImplicitWait(TimeSpan
>   value)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging through the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/dotnet/src/webdriver) in `github` I found that `ImplicitWait` `set` and `get` methods are using (in the lower level) `ICommandExecutor` to set and get the value. The only `FireFoxDriver` constructor witch initialize this variable in the parent `RemoteWebDriver` is

```
public FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverService service, FirefoxOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout) : base(CreateExecutor(service, options, commandTimeout), ConvertOptionsToCapabilities(options))
```

Which triggers the base constructor

```
public RemoteWebDriver(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
```

The method `CreateExecutor` in `FirefoxDriver` (called in the constructor when initializing the base) checks the `firefoxOptions` member `UseLegacyImplementation` and returns `DriverServiceCommandExecutor` when it `false`, which didn't solve the problem, and `FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor` when `true`. `UseLegacyImplementation` is `false` by default, so it should be set to `true`

The solution that worked for me was

```
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions
{
    Profile = fxProfile, // I'm using FirefoxProfile as well
    UseLegacyImplementation = true
};

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), firefoxOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Comment: I will point out that this solution will not work for Firefox 48 and above. By setting the `UseLegacyImplementation` property, you've chosen to use the older, no longer maintained Firefox driver implementation. Automating Firefox 48 or higher requires the use of [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver), which is the default.

Comment: If you're using `options.UseLegacyImplementation = true` as you claim, then I'm sorry, but, no, you're not using geckodriver. The `CreateExecutor` method of the `FirefoxDriver` class explicitly branches on the value of this property, only launching geckodriver if the value is `false`.

Comment: So are there any other ways to set ImplicitlyWait for FIrefoxDriver without legacy support? Have the same exception with geckodriver. Just migrated from Selenium 2.53 to 3.x and due of all these ugly issues really thinking to rollback to 2.53.

Comment: @Yauhen.F From discussion with a colleague I understood that `geckodriver` itself doesn't have implementation to set  `ImplicitWait` yet (should be fixed in newer versions). However I didn't see it an any official source myself so I didn't include this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue in my project. However a short term solution would be to roll back to the previous version of webdriver.

I hope this helps!